# Change origin in image() plot of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, spatial

I have a matrix which can easily be displayed as an image in R with image(). The trouble is the way this matrix is oriented: the origin is intended to be in the lower left corner of the matrix. As a consequence, when the matrix is plotted with the image() function, some of the axis appear backwards (I'm working with large, spatial climate data).

When using the imshow() function from Python's matplotlib, I'm able to pass the option `origin = 'lower'` with the function. Does R have a similar option or a function that could easily perform the transformation I need? I can't imagine that I'm the only person with this problem.

Comment: Basically you can just flip or rotate with some combination of [ and t()

Comment: You might also want to take a look at `rasterImage` . It's a lot faster for large datasets.

Comment: Yeah, I should have explained, I know I need to flip it. It's the memory that I'm really worried about. I guess the dumb-flipping is the best way to go about it. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you by origin mean the first element of the matrix you're already good. Just flip it with `t()` if you want to turn it the other way. If you want to flip it to the way you would look at it in matrix form, i.e. first element in top left corner, flip the first dimension like in the second example.

```
a <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4)
image(t(a))
image(t(a[4:1,]))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use nrow(x):1 or its ncol partner rather than the literal values so it's more general